# Java actionlistener doesn't work

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, actionlistener, mouselistener

I just started learning Java 1 week ago, and I'm a 100% totally beginner. In this code, I can't seem to be able to put an actionlistener/get one to work. I don't even know where/how/in what way to put it, despite reading dozens of tutorials. I've created a JFrame with a JPanel in it, and on the JPanel there's a button. So far so good (and working). But then, I want it to be so that if the button is clicked, another button appears. Thank you sooo much in advance!

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
public class Skeleton extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    //------------------------------------------------
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Skeleton");
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
frame.setContentPane(panel);
    frame.setSize(600,600);
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    JButton button = new JButton("This is a button.");
    JButton button2 = new JButton("Hello");
    panel.setLayout(null);
    button.setBounds(20,20,200,25);
    button2.setBounds(20,70,200,25);
    panel.add(button);
   //-------------------------------------------

button.addMouseListener(this);


}

public void ActionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    System.out.println("Hello");

}
}
```

Answer (score 4):

i will give you some advice

1) Don't implement ActionListener in top classes, use anonymous classes or private classes instead.

Example :

Anonymous class (also call Swing Actions)

```
myComponent.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt){
              //code here
      }

})
```

or

```
//inner class
public class Skeleton{

// in some part
private class MyActionListener implements ActionListener{
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt){
             //code here
       }
}


}
```

2) Your code won't compile cause you are not implementing ActionListener interface

`public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt)` is the signature.

You have to `addActionListener` to your component

`button.addActionListener(this);`

3) Don't use null layout, cause you'll have a lot of problem if you want to add more components or resize windows cause you have to `setBounds` manually and it will be frustrating instead use `[Layout Manager][1]`.

4) Try to not extends JFrame if is not necesary instead have a reference in your class, for example.

```
  public class Skeleton{

    private JFrame frame;

    }
```

Comment: +1 . But I am uncomfortable with your 4rth point. It is always a good way to extend JFrame to harvest its maximum benefits..

Comment: @Mac if you want to add a more level inheritance, i think with composition you can do the same.. at least you want to override some method for example paint.. in that case you can use anonymous classes also..

Comment: But If there is a module which is going to become standard for your entire project then creating a new custom class will minimize a great deal of redundancy by providing you a single module which you can extend(**REUSE**) in your other classes of the same project without worrying about the basic rules..

Comment: @Mac You can do it without inheritance having the frame as delegate in your new custom class, inheritance over implementation is dangerous in my experience, if your new custom class change requirement for some part it isn't to flexible..inheritance breaks encapsulation.

Comment: *inheritance over implementation is dangerous* If not used in correct way. Else it is a big Advantage and lead to reduction in redundancies..

Comment: if you like having a class that have more than 10 types.. i don't see a good design

Comment: @Mac nothing dangerous at all - if you do composition so badly that it hurts, chances are that the version using inheritance is just as bad :-) The core goal is to separation of concerns: a JFrame has no inherent functionality except being the top-level container for your application, it's fully configurable and "fillable" without inheritance. If you end up doing the same configuration over and over again, use f.i. a factory to remove the duplication.

Comment: Thank you everyone, and thank you nachokk for your help. I'm a complete beginner, and your comments actually helped me understand all this Java stuff more. Thank you all so much again!

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the actionlistener.

Register an instance of the event handler class as a listener on one or more components. For example:

```
yourdesiredcomponent.addActionListener(this);
```

For more details check the [doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html)